# Redirect uppercase URL's to lowercase except *** - htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, expressionengine

I'm trying to redirect uppercase URL's to lowercase, but having a bit of a nightmare with it! (Mainly because my .htaccess knowledge is lacking!)

Currently I have:

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling on
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Which works fine, but the CMS I'm using puts pagination links in the URL such as `http://website.com/blog/P8` or `http://website.com/blog/P10` and because the URL's have an uppercase P (Which seems to be required) they are 404 or 301 redirecting.

Is there a rule i could add to make it not pick up on segments of the URL that have a `P` and immediately have at least one numerical character after it? Regex maybe?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I can sympathize with the desire to make URLs  look really nice, but is it important enough to force users to make two requests every time they open a page in your blog?

Comment: I don't follow? Do you mean because it would be checking twice? In theory yes... Because two versions of a URL (UPPERCASE and lowercase) is very bad for SEO -

Comment: Not sure I understand: your CMS is creating URLs like `/blog/P8` and you want them to become `/blog/p8`, correct? My argument is to leave the URL uppercase and not bother. What is the reason for your changing the URLs in the first place?

Comment: Sure, but you won't use any uppercase version, are you? Everywhere around the web, lowercase version will exist, you don't have to bother about uppercase.

Comment: No I want to add an exception for URL's such as /blog/P8 so it never changes the case (Or, only allows uppercase)

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} P[0-9]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]` something like that?

Comment: Possibly? Could you post the full code (Including anything I've added in the original question - If thats needed) As currently adding that line doesn't do anything.

Comment: Wouldn't a canonical meta-tag be a simpler solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an exception like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteMap lc int:tolower

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/P\d+/?$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Or using negative lookahead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(?!.*/P\d+/?$)(.*)$ ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Amazing, that first one works a charm! :) Thank you.