# How to redirect url via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect via `.htaccess`

`https://www.example.co/en/brand/Abc` to `https://www.example.co/en/brand/abc`

I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^https://www.example.co/en/brand/Abc https://www.example.co/en/brand/abc [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect uppercase URL's to lowercase except \*\*\* - htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358972/redirect-uppercase-urls-to-lowercase-except-htaccess)

Answer (score 3):

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument to the `RewriteRule` directive) matches against the path-part of the URL only, ie. `/en/brand/Abc`. An additional complication in per-directory `.htaccess` files is that the URL-path that is matched is also less the *directory prefix* (which always starts with a slash), so the URL-path does not start with a slash. In other words: `en/brand/Abc` (for an `.htaccess` file in the document root).

So, you will need to format the directive like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^en/brand/Abc$ https://www.example.co/en/brand/abc [R=301,L]
```

(Assuming you already have `RewriteEngine On` defined and that this is near the top of your `.htaccess` file.)

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
# Don't want loops
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/abc 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /Abc 
RewriteRule . https://www.example.co/en/brand/abc [R=301,L]
```

URL are usually case-sensitive. [Check this document](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html), while domain names are not. Therefore "abc" and "Abc" are not the same and that's what the question is about. I think.

Comment: Although this will redirect _any_ URL that simply contains `/Abc` anywhere in the URL path, redirecting to the specific target URL (many to one). Also, no need for the additional `RewriteCond` directives - it is better to perform these checks using the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ where possible.